# MySQL query with order and limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume data like:

```
table: shapes

id    type
----------------
1     Square
2     Rectangle
3     Square
4     Square
```

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT `shapes`.* FROM `shapes` WHERE `shapes`.`type` = 'Square' ORDER BY shapes.id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I would expect to receive a row with id: 4.  Unexpectedly, I'm receiving a row with id: 1.

For the really strange part:  If I execute the same query with `LIMIT 2`:

```
SELECT `shapes`.* FROM `shapes` WHERE `shapes`.`type` = 'Square' ORDER BY shapes.id DESC LIMIT 2
```

The first row in that set of 2 is actually the correct row!

And to add to the strangeness still, I have another copy of this database within the same MySQL server, and it returns the correct row for any limit query, `LIMIT 1` or otherwise.

The only answer I can come to is to dump and reload the database, but I'd like to understand why this is happening first before taking that action, if possible.

tl;dr: `LIMIT 1` returns the wrong row.  `LIMIT 2` returns the correct row (for the first one).  Seems to be database specific.

Comment: Upon further review, a coworker helped discover another oddity.  If I set 'limit 2' instead of 'limit 1' in the query, the correct top result is returned.  Even more perverse is that when I run the same query on a similar dataset in a different database within the same MySQL instance, the query returns the correct data.  I'm now of a belief that this problem is isolated to a single MySQL database, but perplexed as to what could cause this behavior.

Comment: (I've edited the question to reflect the discovery above, and remove the Rails distractors which didn't have anything to do with the problem)

Comment: Tried to repair/analyze the table?

Comment: I tried variants of `CHECK TABLE`, `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, to no avail.  Just now, I ran an `EXPLAIN` on the query, determined which index was being used in that query, then dropped and re-created that index.  This has solved the problem.  It doesn't make me feel any better, but I think it has to be chalked up to a MySQL bug of some sort. :/

Comment: Feel better, on the contrary: you've learned that MySQL indexes can become corrupt, and how to repair them. :-)

Comment: Heading to off-topic land myself here (I'm censoring my database engine preferences! :)), but it does give me pause as to what other indexes may be lurking in a similar situation -- not causing overt errors, but returning incorrect or misleading results...  I wonder if there is any way to detect the situation without blindly rebuilding everything?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I would have assumed that any or all of check, optimize and repair table statements would highlight/fix broken indexes... And a quick google search reveals none either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused as you are not using limit 0, 1. While not provided the full query sometimes it display wrong results. I suggest you to type/execute the full query.

Comment: For fun, I did try as you suggested, but no change.  From the documentation: "LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments...", or more precisely, from the syntax guide:  `LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}`

Comment: Then the you have to check whether there is any trigger or procedure is associated with table or not. It generally happen in those cases